# ImageMagick convert chokes on a large PNG, makes system nearly freeze

Tags: linux, memory, freeze, imagemagick, png

I have this PNG file which I want to convert to JPG format. It's a little large - about 20,000 x 30,000 pixels (but compressed very well, i.e. 780 KB). I'm running

```
convert myfile.png myfile.jpg
```

and what I see is that `convert` immediate eats up all available memory, and all other apps become exceedingly slow. I don't see very high CPU usage, though. After waiting for about a minute I start killing other apps, which did not help; and eventually I gave up and killed `convert` itself.

Why is this happening? After all, it should be quite possible to decompress the image in 'tiles', and write the JPEG that way. And even you want the whole image at once - it's still just 600 Mpixels, i.e. under 2 GB, a lot less than my total (and my available) memory. I don't get it.

Notes:

- I'm using Kubuntu GNU/Linux 16.04 with LXDE and a stock kernel, on an Intel i5 3570K. So while it's not the latest machine, it's capable enough.
- I have 8 GB total and had 4 GB available when I started the run.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's going to have to try to uncompress it before it can re-compress it... that's going to take RAM... a lot of it, even in segments it eventually has to find somewhere to put it all. idk nix very well, but can you expand your virtual memory to encompass it?

Comment: @Tetsujin: 1. I have enough RAM for the entire image 2. Why should it have to uncompress the whole image? 3. gimp uncompresses it just fine...

Comment: Are you using the 64-buit binary? What happens if you use the limit switch to force disk caching and limit memory usage (slower than in memory obviously) "-limit memory 2mb -limit map 4mb"